# ASP.Net label value changed in JQuery but unchanged at postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label

The original value of the ASP.Net label is "xyz".

I have changed the ASP.Net Label value as below:

```
$("#<%= lblNew.ClientID %>").text("123");
```

It changed on the web page.  But when I click on the button and get the value of the label, it is changed back to the previous value "xyz" instead of "123".

```
Response.Write(lblNew.Text);
```

I have tried to set the html of the label instead of the text as below: but it doesn't work either.

```
$("#<%= lblNew.ClientID %>").html("123");
```

How can I get the value changed by Jquery?  Thanks.

Comment: Use HiddenFiled

pls look :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266872/jquery-set-text-value-is-lost-after-postback

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266872/jquery-set-text-value-is-lost-after-postback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because label text value is loaded from view state.Your jquery change the value of label but didn't change view state where it value is being loaded on postback....
But you want the change label text..so you can get it like this.......

```
string lblvalue=Request[lblNew.UniqueID] as string;
```

Here is and example to understand how view state work with label...refrence [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" 
  Font-Name="Verdana" Text="Hello, World!"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" 
  Text="Change Message" ID="btnSubmit"></asp:Button>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Empty Postback"></asp:Button>
And the code-behind class contains the following event handler for the Button's Click event:
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblMessage.Text = "Goodbye, Everyone!";
}
```

illustrates the sequence of events that transpire, highlighting why the change to the Label's Text property needs to be stored in the view state.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem faced by you is use the hidden field and update its value along with the label field , When the Postback will happen you can read the updated value from the hidden field

Answer (score 1):

Try `.val()` instead

```
$("#<%= lblNew.ClientID %>").val("123");
```

Documentation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value

**EDIT:**

I misread your question and `.text` should be fine. I think the issue is more to do with the postback. Can you confirm how the code `$("#<%= lblNew.ClientID %>").text("123");` is called? If it's on `$(document).ready()` then it should be fine. But it's is a result of an action that will get lost when the postback is made / DOM is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter ASP.Net Labels in Javascript/JQuery and expect them to persist on postback.

Only values from input controls (like textboxes, radio controls, radiobuttons, etc...) are posted to the server.