# JQuery set text value is lost after postback

Tags: jquery, .net

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function btnSetText_OnClientClick() {
$("#<%= lbl1.ClientID %>").text("123");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="btnSetText" runat="server" Text="Set Text" OnClientClick="btnSetText_OnClientClick(); return false;" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string str1 = lbl1.Text;
}
```

The scenario here is when user click "set text", the jquery script will update the label value, when the Submit button is click, the value for lbl1.Text is always "", which is lost after postback occurs, any ideas ?

Comment: Well that is how its supposed to happen.On postback it clears all element value.

Comment: any work around to fix this logic ?

Comment: i don't see a logic to fix this.Actually why are you trying to do this.Show me the exact problem

Comment: use javascript cookie

Comment: The actual case is we have a date picker tools that will update user selected date to a label, when post back occur the label value is empty, so I simplify the scenario to this snippets.

Comment: Since the span(label) tag generated at the server never had any value, after postback there will be nothing to restore it with.

You can use a hidden field to transfer the value to the server and then set it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use A `HiddenField` To Get The value after postback

Try This

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="../js/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function btnSetText_OnClientClick() {
$("#<%= lbl1.ClientID %>").text("123");
$('#HiddenFileldVariable').val($("#<%= lbl1.ClientID %>").text());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="btnSetText" runat="server" Text="Set Text" OnClientClick="btnSetText_OnClientClick(); return false;" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFileldVariable" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string str1 = HiddenFileldVariable.Value;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that the problem could be related to the EnableViewState property for your asp.net button; It has to be 'true' for the value to be passed into the postback handler.

I've done a little test on my side and I'm able to reproduce your problem if EnableViewState is 'false'; It works if I set it to 'true'.

I hope it helps,

Roger

Comment: ViewState data stored in a HiddenField by ASP.NET for the state to maintain. 
ASP.NET doesn't know anything about the value set by JQuery to maintain it. Best way it to make a HiddenField, and store the JQuery value to that too. So that it can be read by ASP.NET, and set the textbox value again.