# ASP Webforms hidden input lose value on postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, ispostback

I have the following hidden input field on a `aspx` page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="MySecretValue" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="submit_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some stuff

}
```

The hidden input is populated via some jQuery script. When the user submits the page I do some stuff inside the `submit_Click` method and redisplay the page. However when the page redisplays the hidden input field is empty. How do I ensure the hidden field keeps the value when the page is re-displayed?

Comment: @Samundra don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: Did you try to debug and find out where exactly your value lost?

Answer (score 0):

This code does not lose value after post back ...Try this

Enable `EnableViewState="true"` in page directive or web.config

.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflow_Solve.Others.WebForm1" EnableViewState="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //First time loaded value
             console.log($('#MySecretValue').val());
            $('#setHiddenValue').click(function() {
                $('#MySecretValue').val('1');
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="MySecretValue" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Save"  CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
            onclick="Submit_Click" />
    </div>
    <div id="setHiddenValue">setHiddenValueByClick me</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and .aspx.cs

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do all stuff
            String a = MySecretValue.Value;
            var dd = a;
        }
    }
```

This link may help you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266872/jquery-set-text-value-is-lost-after-postback)

Comment: I want to maintian the posted value, so if i populate the field with `xyz` using jquery and then post it, the page should redisplay - correct? When it redisplays, the field should have the value `xyz` unless I've misunderstood how post back and viewstate works?