# Updating Quantity of product without doing Postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, function, repeater

I am doing a project in which I stuck in one situation.

When I add to cart I need to check for the quantity added as well as the product and I'm using a JQuery function to do this.

While the user has not checked out, I am storing that `qty` and `product_id` in one data table. If the user removes the product I change the qty as well.

But when I add a product in the cart at that time post back is not happening . So Qty which is bound to another data table (using database) is not updating its value. So I am getting confused what to do Please help me to Sort this problem out.

#### `InsertProduct`

```
function InsertProduct(product_id, qty, totalqty) {
    if (qty == "Details") {
        debugger;

        if ($('#txtqty').val().trim() != "") {
            if (!validateTextNumericInRange($('#txtqty').val())) {
                 alert("You have entered invalid product Quantity.");
                 return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
         qty = "1";
         price_type = 'sale';
    }

    debugger;

    var tempqty;
    if (qty == "Details") {
        tempqty = $('#lblcurrent_stock').text();
    } else {
        totalqty = parseInt(totalqty,10)

        if (totalqty != 0) {
            totalqty=totalqty-1;
            tempqty=totalqty; 
        } else {
            alert("Sorry We Are Running Of Stock For this Product. Will Soon Update the Stock");
            return false;
        }
    }

    $('#target').show();
    $('#target').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader1.gif" style="margin-left: 50%;padding: 10px;"/>')
    $.get("minicart.aspx?product_id="+product_id+"&qty="+qty+"&price="+pricetype_prescription+"&price_type="+price_type+"&tempqty="+tempqty+"#minicart", function( data ) {

        var resourceContent = data; 

        data = $(data).find('div#minicart');
        $('#target').html(data);
          
        var mini = $(resourceContent).find('div#pnlminicart')
         
        $('#smallcart').html(mini);
        $('#target').delay(7000).slideUp('slow');

        // can be a global variable too...
        // process the content...
    });
 return false;
}
```

Here `detail` is for another page that is working properly. The this is I am not able to get the `totalqty` value updated. Here `validateTextNumericInRange` is used for validation of the qty.

Comment: Debug in firebug and see what is the error.

Comment: i have done that... but as here postback is not happening so thats why value of totalqty is not changing the value...

Comment: If you have the labels inside any container, it is likely that asp.net changed the ids of lblcurrent_stock and other controls. You can check rendered html.

Comment: nop... i want to update the quantity... i have tried everything available on internet.. but not succeeded... i know there must be some way for that... but still not got any

Comment: Can you post rendered html of txtqty and lblcurrent_stock? Remember, the code you have posted is not enough to recreate the issue in test.

Comment: txtqty and lblcurrent_stock is used for product_details page that part is already done. Now just remaining part is product page. In which i am stuck.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: Yes... I have found the solution... BUt alternate solution... that is not related to this question...

Comment: I have found alternate solution for this question. So now this question is now off the topic for me.

Comment: It may be off-topic for you, but it looks perfectly valid for the forum.

Answer (score 1):

If you display the information in a label control even if you update the quantity with jQuery when you fire your postback function it will read the original quantity from the viewstate. I had the same problem. I found a workaround:
[ASP.Net label value changed in JQuery but unchanged at postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317821/asp-net-label-value-changed-in-jquery-but-unchanged-at-postback)

Store the quantity also in a not visible textbox and read the value from it when postback.